# Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [German Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://german.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Grammaticality of "original italienisches Eis"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6764/grammaticality-of-original-italienisches-eis)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Does German phonetics fully determine the spelling?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6781/does-german-phonetics-fully-determine-the-spelling)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to say "to check the mail"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/how-to-say-to-check-the-mail)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Wie sagt man "Do you know if something?" auf Deutsch?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6824/wie-sagt-man-do-you-know-if-something-auf-deutsch)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Welche Präpositionen folgen auf "Portierung" (Softwareportierung)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6872/welche-prapositionen-folgen-auf-portierung-softwareportierung)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [When speaking about oneself, should Konjunktiv I or Indikativ be used?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6888/when-speaking-about-oneself-should-konjunktiv-i-or-indikativ-be-used)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Apostrophe with or without space? (»mit’m« vs. »mit ’m«)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6878/apostrophe-with-or-without-space-mitm-vs-mit-m)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Verwendung von Nein nach negativen Fragen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/verwendung-von-nein-nach-negativen-fragen)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [»Passt das dir?« oder »Passt dir das?«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/passt-das-dir-oder-passt-dir-das)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Das Wort "ich" in offiziellen Schreiben](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/das-wort-ich-in-offiziellen-schreiben)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

Answer (score 2):

Being more of an outsider to this SE site, I notice that it's one of those low-voting sites (similar to AskUbuntu).

There a some avid and dedicated members that will converge on a new question and answer it very quickly, but I also find that answers - like on many other SE sites - get accepted too quickly. Generally I see this as discouragement for others who may indeed come up with a more succinct answer.

Comment: Is this a low-voting site? Then I'll have to take a look at some others. This site seems to me a "votes for all" heaven. But it might be because I spend a lot of time in Stack Overflow, and there you can be happy not to get crucified when asking a question.